# NL char when useing imagestring in php

Tags: php, newline

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could remove or replace these annoying N over L (I'm guessing means newline) from my php string before printing them to an image.

the text looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIpWK.png)

any help much appreciated as I have wasted hours on this little problem...

```
<?php
exec('/usr/games/fortune -s', $fortune);
for($i = 0; $i <= count($fortune); $i++) {
    $text = "$text $fortune[$i]";
}
$image = imagecreatefrompng("rex.png");
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 35, "\n", true);
$newertext2 = explode  ("\n", $newtext);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 0, $newertext2[0], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 11, $newertext2[1], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 22, $newertext2[2], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 33, $newertext2[3], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 44, $newertext2[4], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 55, $newertext2[5], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 66, $newertext2[6], $color);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 77, $newertext2[7], $color);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newertext2 = explode  ("\n", $newtext);
imagestring  ($image, 3, 0, 0, $newertext[0], $color);
```

Shouldn't you print the letters in newertext2 instead of newertext ?

Comment: heh, yeah, i just made that edit before I posted and hadn't saved it yet. editing now.

Comment: also, that has nothing to do with the problem i'm having. just me not looking before i post.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer:

I found out that every whitespace character except of new line and space is replaced by a "NL" symbol. e.g. the tab sign.

A solution could be to replace them like this:

[preg_replace all spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175655/preg-replace-all-spaces)

Of course you should replace by a space instead of a underscore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for write the content by respecting whitespaces.

This function will not exceed the image's sizes limits.
If a new line is not able to be added entirely in once, it will be exploded in smallest lines.

```php
/**
 * @author Booteille
 *
 * @param resource $image
 * @param int $font
 * @param int $x
 * @param int $y
 * @param string $string
 * @param int $color
 */
function whitespaces_imagestring($image, $font, $x, $y, $string, $color) {
    $font_height = imagefontheight($font);
    $font_width = imagefontwidth($font);
    $image_height = imagesy($image);
    $image_width = imagesx($image);
    $max_characters = (int) ($image_width - $x) / $font_width ;
    $next_offset_y = $y;

    $i = 0;
    $exploded_string = explode("\n", $string);
    $i_count = count($exploded_string);

    for(; $i < $i_count; ++$i) {
        $exploded_wrapped_string = explode("\n", wordwrap(str_replace("\t", "    ", $exploded_string[$i]), $max_characters, "\n"));

        $j = 0;
        $j_count = count($exploded_wrapped_string);

        for(; $j < $j_count; ++$j) {
            imagestring($image, $font, $x, $next_offset_y, $exploded_wrapped_string[$j], $color);
            $next_offset_y += $font_height;

            if($next_offset_y >= $image_height - $y) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```