# preg_replace all spaces

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace all spaces with underscores and the following is not working:

```
$id = "aa aa";
echo $id;
preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $id);
echo $id;
```

prints

```
aa aaaa aa
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The function `preg_replace` doesn't modify the string in-place. It returns a new string with the result of the replacement. You should assign the result of the call back to the `$id` variable:

```
$id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $id);
```

Comment: Note that if your page is encoded with UTF-8 then you must add the unicode modifier to the end of the regular expression, so it becomes preg_replace('/\s+/u', '_', $id);  Failure to add this could cause invalid characters in your UTF-8 encoded text. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43849130/649497

Comment: @BruceHill  omg thanks for that pointer, I wasted hours because I didn't add the unicode modifier...

Answer (score 17):

I think `str_replace()` might be more appropriate here:

```
$id = "aa aa";
$id = str_replace(' ', '_', $id);
echo $id;
```

Comment: This code does not reproduce what OP is trying to do, however.

Comment: @VincentSavard: "replace all spaces with underscores"...I think it does :)

Comment: His sentence leaves place to interpretation, but his code does not. Your code will replace every single space to an underscore, while he apparently wants to replace every group of whitespace characters to a single underscore.

Comment: @VincentSavard: He also said "the following is not working", which means his code was incorrect for what he was trying to accomplish, i.e. "replace all spaces with underscores". I agree it could be ambiguous though :)

Comment: ... yes, because he obviously throws away the result of preg_replace.

Answer (score 13):

You have forgotten to assign the result of `preg_replace` into your `$id`

```
$id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $id);
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, in linux/unix environment,

```
$strippedId = preg_replace('/\h/u', '',  $id);
```

Try this as well.

Comment: Thank you for this. Bugged me not knowing why I couldn't get rid of some spaces in a special output

Comment: The /u modified did it for me. Seems \s doesn't cover caps space! why is there a caps space in UTF8!!!

Answer (score 2):

We need to replace the space in the string "aa aa" with '_' (underscore). The \s+ is used to match multiple spaces. The output will be "aa_aa"

```
<?php

$id = "aa aa";
$new_id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $id);
echo $new_id;

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of how this code works?

Comment: We need to replace the space in the string "aa aa"  with '_'(underscore).
\s+ is used to match multiple spaces.
The output will be "aa_aa"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.btw I am new to StackOverflow.