# Replacing empty space with preg_replace causes invalid characters with UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, preg-replace, windows-server-2008

Our `PHP` web application (`PHP 5.6.30` running on `Windows Server 2008 R2`) uses `UTF-8` encoding but needs to import data from files that are encoded using `Windows-1252`. When the data is imported it is converted to `UTF-8` as follows.

```
iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $value);
```

When we import the following sample data, the conversion works correctly for most of the `Windows-1252` characters, but in line 8 below, the `à` character gives problems and is not correctly converted.

```
1;€
2;é
3;è
4;ë
5;ï
6;ä
7;á
8;à
9;ç
10;ß
11;ø 
12;í
13;ì
14;ñ
15;@
16;û
```

Here is a screenshot showing the result of displaying this data on the website.

[image]

Does anyone know why the `PHP` `iconv` is not correctly converting the `à` character?

Comment: And the critical value of `$this->encoding` is?

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, that value is `Windows-1252`. Will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Have you tried using headers encoding? or `iconv_set_encoding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue and it ended up having nothing to do with `iconv` like I initially thought. The change that was required was such a small one, only one character, but it took me ages to hunt this down. It turns out that the offending statement was actually the following:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$columnvalue))
```

The purpose of this regular expression is to remove white space from the value, but because the encoding was `UTF-8` this `regular expression` had a residual effect of corrupting the `à` character. I resolved this but adding `u` (`unicode modifier`) to the end of the regular expression definition. So the expression became:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ',$columnvalue))
```

And then the encoding of the page was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my two cents.

[`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) depends on the current defined locale. Using characters not supported by the current locale will result in a invalid `�` UTF-8 character (typically characters with an accent `à`, `é`, `è`, `ù` ...).

As per @BruceHill pointed out you can use the regex `/u` to properly identify UTF-8 characters.

> **Regex `u` flag (PCRE_UTF8)**
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl.
> Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.
> An invalid subject will cause the `preg_*` function to match nothing;
> An invalid pattern will trigger an error of level `E_WARNING`.
> Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid.

- See @https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Alternatives are setting the current locale to the currently used one `setlocale( LC_ALL, 'fr_FR' );` OR decoding the string to `ISO-8859-1`, passing it to `preg_replace` then re-encoding it to `UTF-8`.

As [`utf8_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) and [`utf8_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) are being deprecated we can use `mb_convert_encoding( $buffer, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8' );` and `mb_convert_encoding( $buffer, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1' );`.